# Calling anything after switching iframes in chrome causes Error - Python Selenium (Chrome)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

My problem is that when I switch to an iframe in python selenium, everything stops working. For example, I can call:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH HERE).click()
```

before switching iframes and it works fine, but as soon as I call the code

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it)
```

everything stops working after the frame successfully switches.

I have switched from Chromedriver to geckodriver for firefox, and the code works without error.

I've encountered this problem ever since I downloaded the new chromedriver as my chrome browser is now version 76. I did try redownloading the chromedriver as well.

I have tried testing if there was any changes in the identifying features I used to tell the driver what to do. This includes making sure the XPATHs are still the same, the ID is still the same.

I have also tried checking if the element was located in the correct iframe or if the iframe has changed.

None of these worked.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it).(By.ID "iframehere")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH HERE).click()
```

I expected the code to run successfully, like literally a day before I had to download a new chromedriver to accomodate chrome version 76. Or how it works without errors on geckodriver.

Now, I have this error:

```
JavascriptException: javascript error: unhandled object (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
```

Comment: Please when you create a post insert code in the block code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When clicking on an element after `<iframe>` switching you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Sample Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframehere")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "XPATH HERE"))).click()
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: My code already had this. It kept timing out, so that's when I went exploring and removed the webdriver wait. I realised, even though it can switch frames and it's not giving me "cannot find element error". That's why I omitted that part from my code example.

I don't know why, but ever since I updated to chrome 76, this javascript error keeps appearing even though the code worked fine before.

Answer (score 0):

I had in the past problems with Selenium while using `WebDriverWait()` and in some cases I did overcome them simply by using

```
import time
time.sleep(maximum_time_needed_to_load_form)
```

And a very good solution but did the trick.